# ExpressibleByStringLiteral with optionals in function parameters

Tags: swift, string, option-type

Consider the following enum

```swift
enum Text: Equatable {
    case plain(String)
    case attributed(NSAttributedString)
}
```

I've made it conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`

```swift
extension Text: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public typealias StringLiteralType = String
    
    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = .plain(value)
    }
}
```

With all this, I can do the following, just like I would expect:

```swift
let text: Text = "Hello" // .plain("Hello")
let text2: Text? = "Hello" // .plain("Hello")
```

But I get compiler errors for the following:

```swift
let nilString: String? = nil
let text3: Text? = nilString // Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Text?'

func foo(text: Text?) { /** foo **/ }
let text = "Hello"
foo(text: text) // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Text?'

func bar(text: Text?) { /** bar **/ }
bar(text: nilString) // Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Text?'
```

How can I get those to work ?

I've also tried to extend `Optional: ExpressibleByStringLiteral where Wrapped: ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Show your foo and bar implementations. Why would you declare you object optional when initializing it with a string literal?

Comment: @LeoDabus for the sake of the example. In real code I'm using functions that accept `String?` and call other functions that require `Text?`. There are no implementations for `foo` nor `bar` since that code alone throws compiler errors

Comment: Just deal with your optional. What's wrong with checking its optionality and unwrapping it?

Comment: Resuming **"Valid types for StringLiteralType are String and StaticString."** If you would like to deal with optional strings when initializing your Text just create a fallible initializer for that. `init?(_ string: String?) {` `guard let string = string else { return nil }` `self = .plain(string)` `}` and then  `let text3 = Text(nilString)`

Comment: You're right, I've read on a few additional posts on optionals, and the answer is always that you should turn them in concrete types as soon as possible. So for now I'll simply use `nilString.map { .plain($0) }`, does the trick. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `nilString.map(Text.plain)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExpressibleByStringLiteral is not about automatic casting(String, Int) to your custom type. Literal is exactly `"word"` (**string literal**) or `12.63` (**Double literal**).
But in your example `let text = "Hello"` constant text has type **String**. But method foo expect type **Text?** for argument.

But you can use it like

```
foo(text: "Some text")
```

Now compiler know that it can convert your String literal to Text. And then wrap it into `Optional<Text>`.